# Using PnP PowerShell to find shares in Site / Document Library?

Tags: powershell, document-library, site, pnp-powershell, share

I am trying to find the list of shares in a site / document library / list using PnPPowerShell.

Does such a Commandlet exist ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a moment and check the official [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps)  of PnP Powershell.

This might be the command You are looking for: Get-PnPListItem ( [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps) ).